# Using A Dropdown Menu to Order a List Taken from a Database Simaultaneously With Pagination

Tags: php, html, pagination, sql-order-by

I hope that title makes sense.... Basically I created PHP script to take data from a database and display in, I then wrote some code to use a drop down menu to order that data. That all worked ok until I tried to utilise some pagination. I can make the pagination work, and I can make the ordering work, but not at the same time! At the moment the code that I have will allow me to order the list and almost paginate it. There are 40 results and I want to display 10 at a time. When not using the ordering code I can paginate it perfectly but when I try to intergrate the two bits of code it will only display the first 10 results and not give me an option to go to the next page to see the rest! (please bear in mind that I only started learning 5 das ago so I am still getting to grips with it!

The code:

if (!isset($_GET['start'])) 
   {

$_GET['start'] = 0; 
   }

$per_page = 10;
   $start = $_GET['start'];

```
if (!$start)
   $start = 0;



$sort = @$_POST['order'];  
if (!empty($sort)) {   
$get = mysql_query("SELECT bookname, bookauthor, bookpub, bookisbn
            FROM booktable
            ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order'])." ASC
            LIMIT $start, $per_page");
}
 else { 
$get = mysql_query("SELECT bookname, bookauthor, bookpub, bookisbn 
                FROM booktable 
                ORDER BY bookname ASC
                LIMIT $start, $per_page"); 
}

$record_count = mysql_num_rows($get);


?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['showerror']))
$errorcode = $_GET['showerror'];
else
$errorcode = 0;
?>
```

wont include all the html rubbish and the ordering menu!

```
<div id="mid">

<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>";

echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book Title";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book Author";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book Publisher";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";
echo "Book ISBN";
echo "</th>";
echo "<th>";

echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
 // get data
 $bookname = $row['bookname'];
 $bookauthor = $row['bookauthor'];
 $bookpub = $row['bookpub'];
 $bookisbn = $row['bookisbn'];



    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='addtolist.php?bookname=".$bookname."&bookauthor=".$bookauthor."&bookpub=".$bookpub."&bookisbn=".$bookisbn."'>Add to basket</a>";

    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookname;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookauthor;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookpub;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $bookisbn;
    echo "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";


}

echo "</table>";

$prev = $start - $per_page;
$next = $start + $per_page;

if (!($start<=0))
       echo "<a href='products.php?start=$prev'>Prev</a> ";

       //set variable for first page number
$i=1;

//show page numbers
for ($x = 0; $x < $record_count; $x = $x + $per_page)
{
 if ($start != $x)
    echo "<a class='pagin' href='products.php?start=$x'> $i </a>";
 else
    echo "<a class='pagin' href='products.php?start=$x'><b> $i </b></a>";
 $i++;
}

//show next button
if (!($start >= $record_count - $per_page))
       echo "<a class='pagin' href='products.php?start=$next'> Next </a>";
?>
```

Thank you so much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest way just change `$sort = @$_POST['order'];` to `$sort = @$_REQUEST['order'];` and add to your pagination links `&order=$order`

Comment: Thank you for your response - changed the post to request but when you say add &order=$order to the pagination links, do I put them in the if else statement, what does the & mean?

Comment: I mean add order to `echo "<a class='pagin' href='products.php?start={$x}&order={$order}'>";` to save order when paging